I cant deploy my solidity contract, it keeps saying invalid character
I am new to Solidity and smart contracts but I am trying to deploy a smart contract on remix-ide. It's a snipping arbitrage bot that's supposed to trade Ethereum but when I try to deploy it, Remix gives an error message that says "invalid character." I am not sure what is wrong.
I tried rewriting it multiple times and compiling it in different ways but it still doesn't work I don't know what else to do.
I've added a screenshot with the problem after clicking deploy, and the code I used
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
        pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

    import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
    import "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
    import "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

    contract ArbitrageBot {
        address public owner;
        IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapRouter;
        IUniswapV2Factory public uniswapFactory;
        address public weth;

      event ArbitrageSuccess(address token, uint256 ethSpent, uint256 tokenAmount);

        modifier onlyOwner() {
            require(msg.sender == owner, "Not the contract owner");
            _;
        }

        constructor(address _uniswapRouter, address _weth) {
            owner = msg.sender;
            uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_uniswapRouter);
            uniswapFactory = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapRouter.factory());
            weth = _weth;
        }

        // Function to execute an arbitrage buy of a token using ETH
        function executeArbitrage(address token, uint256 amountEthToSpend) external onlyOwner payable {
            require(msg.value >= amountEthToSpend, "Not enough ETH provided");

            // Get reserves to check if liquidity is sufficient
            address pairAddress = uniswapFactory.getPair(weth, token);
            require(pairAddress != address(0), "No liquidity pool available for this token");

            (uint256 reserveWeth, uint256 reserveToken,) = getReserves(pairAddress);

            // Ensure liquidity exists
            require(reserveWeth > 0 && reserveToken > 0, "Insufficient liquidity");

            // Set up path array for swapping ETH -> Token            
                address[] memory myPath = new address[](2);
                myPath[0] = weth;
                myPath[1] = token;

                uniswapRouter.swapExactETHForTokens{value: amountEthToSpend}(
                    0, // Set a default value for the minimum output since we don't need it in this case
                    myPath,
                    address(this),
                    block.timestamp + 300
                );
        
            uint256 tokenBalance = IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this));

            // Emit success event
            emit ArbitrageSuccess(token, amountEthToSpend, tokenBalance);
        }

        // Withdraw function to get ETH out of the contract
        function withdrawETH() external onlyOwner {
            payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance);
        }

        // Withdraw any ERC20 tokens out of the contract
        function withdrawToken(address token) external onlyOwner {
            uint256 tokenBalance = IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this));
            IERC20(token).transfer(owner, tokenBalance);
        }

        // Helper function to get reserves from the Uniswap pair
        function getReserves(address pairAddress) public view returns (uint256 reserveWeth, uint256 reserveToken, uint256 timestamp) {
            IUniswapV2Pair pair = IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress);
            (uint256 reserve0, uint256 reserve1, uint256 lastTimestamp) = pair.getReserves();
            (reserveWeth, reserveToken) = pair.token0() == weth ? (reserve0, reserve1) : (reserve1,     reserve0);
            return (reserveWeth, reserveToken, lastTimestamp);
        }

        // Helper function to calculate the minimum output token amount for a swap
        function calculateAmountOutMin(uint256 amountIn, uint256 reserveIn, uint256 reserveOut)       public pure returns (uint256) {
            uint256 amountInWithFee = amountIn * 997; // Uniswap's 0.3% fee
            uint256 numerator = amountInWithFee * reserveOut;
            uint256 denominator = (reserveIn * 1000) + amountInWithFee;
            return numerator / denominator;
        }

        // Allow the contract to receive ETH
        receive() external payable {}
    }

Visual IDE Error

check out first line "// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT`", is the last character "`" correct?

That is not in the actual code, i was having trouble pasting the code here so it is a typo after pasting it here

please fix the code then or better, use pastebin

I removed the " ' "
